# Using css next variables globaly

Tags: css, postcss, cssnext

I have postcss parser set up with http://cssnext.github.io and am trying to figure out a way to set up a `variables.css` file to contain all my theme settings.

So far `variable.css` looks like this with a couple of vars

```
:root {
  --color-white: #FFF;
  --color-black: #000;
}
```

I than import it into my other files where I want to use these variables, so `@import './variables.css'` or similar and then use it in that file like `background-color: var(--color-white)` for example, however I get follwoing warning:

> variable '--color-white' is undefined and used without a fallback
> [postcss-custom-properties]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to install postcss import

`$ npm install postcss-import`

Check this [post](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import) for more details how to install.

**EDIT**
Using `postcss-import` solved the issue, however there are currently issues with latest version, use v 7.x for stability

Answer (score 2):

Another solution if you want to share your variables with your JavaScript code, is to rely on postcss-custom-properties "variables" options.

Here is an example of a postcss-cssnext config to pass global variables

```
require("postcss-cssnext")({
  features: {
    customProperties: {
      variables: {
        mainColor: "red",
        altColor: "blue",
      }
    }
  }
})
```

https://cssnext.github.io/usage/#features